# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.training.experimental.mixed_precision' has no attribute '_register_wrapper_optimizer_cls'

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am using Keras to implement a neural network. But when I use `model = Sequential()`, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-fa9fd3b0e211> in <module>
      8 
      9 # Create the model
---> 10 model = Sequential()
     11 model.add(Dropout(0.1), input_shape=(128,))
     12 model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/version_utils.py in __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
     55     use_v2 = should_use_v2()
     56     cls = swap_class(cls, training.Model, training_v1.Model, use_v2)  # pylint: disable=self-cls-assignment
---> 57     return super(ModelVersionSelector, cls).__new__(cls)
     58 
     59 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py in __getattr__(self, item)
     60 
     61   def __getattr__(self, item):
---> 62     module = self._load()
     63     return getattr(module, item)
     64 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py in _load(self)
     43     """Load the module and insert it into the parent's globals."""
     44     # Import the target module and insert it into the parent's namespace
---> 45     module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
     46     self._parent_module_globals[self._local_name] = module
     47 

/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    124                 break
    125             level += 1
--> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    127 
    128 

/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec)

/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py in exec_module(self, module)

/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_v1.py in <module>
     48 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import input_spec
     49 from tensorflow.python.keras.mixed_precision import autocast_variable
---> 50 from tensorflow.python.keras.mixed_precision import loss_scale_optimizer
     51 from tensorflow.python.keras.mixed_precision import policy
     52 from tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model import layer_serialization

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/mixed_precision/loss_scale_optimizer.py in <module>
   1152 
   1153 # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 1154 mixed_precision._register_wrapper_optimizer_cls(optimizer_v2.OptimizerV2,
   1155                                                 LossScaleOptimizerV1)
   1156 

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.training.experimental.mixed_precision' has no attribute '_register_wrapper_optimizer_cls'
```

I am relatively new to deep learning. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This problem maybe occurs in the keras package version.

Because the installed tensorflow version does not match the keras version. Just uninstall keras and reinstall your own tensorflow corresponding version.

```
pip3 uninstall keras
pip3 install keras --upgrade
```

In summary, you need to match the correct environment version for your Keras code.

Comment: I tried reinstalling keras but that didn't work. However, I don't know why but the same code works fine on a new jupyter notebook. Anyways, thanks for your help!

Comment: New jupyter notebook? Maybe because your numpy is provide from different python environments(?

Comment: Your answer is the best given and should be marked as the correct answer. With pip install tf-nightly the problem is not properly addressed.  Hint: maybe you want to add like moguztas copy of your solution did.

Answer (score 11):

I've been searching a lot and I could fix this problem only running the following command that I found in this [source, Github tf issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/51850):

```sh
    pip3 install tf-nightly
```

As the other answers, this is a compatible version issue

I was getting problems with imports in my local machine like:

```py
    from tensorflow.keras import layers
    from tensorflow.keras import Input
```

But now I can import without problem.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. The problem is that Keras is not installed compatible with Tensorflow, so there are no attributes/methods in it. I tried the following commands mentioned in the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58639231)  and my problem was completely solved.

```
pip3 uninstall keras
pip3 install keras --upgrade
```

Comment: This didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 7):

This is a terrible solution, but for the sake of getting things going, here is how I solved it.

I went into my directory and found the location of tensorflow.python.training.experimental.mixed_precision.py, and manually inserted the following lines

```
def _register_wrapper_optimizer_cls(optimizer_cls, wrapper_optimizer_cls):
  _REGISTERED_WRAPPER_OPTIMIZER_CLS[optimizer_cls] = wrapper_optimizer_cls
```

The code is from the official GitHub
https://github.com/sourcecode369/tensorflow-1/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/experimental/mixed_precision.py

Comment: I would rather upvote (did already!) because in my experience and opinion, in emergency deadlines, quick and dirty solutions are life-saving than mature ones. Additionally, answerer has given a disclaimer that THIS IS A TERRIBLE SOLUTION so one should use at their own risk ;-)

Comment: Be honest this was only working solution for me. Tried to reinstall packages in many ways, but no success. Clear it is one time fix though.

Answer (score 1):

After tried both of commands below:

```
pip3 uninstall keras
pip3 install keras --upgrade
```

Or:

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow
pip3 install tensorflow --upgrade
```

The only solution works for me:

```
pip3 install tensorflow==2.6.0
pip3 install keras==2.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If below commands doesn't work，

```
pip3 uninstall keras
pip3 install keras --upgrade
```

It might the `pip3 uninstall keras` doesn't uninstall the keras clearly.
You need to use `pip list` to check whether there are some keras package still install.